# Simple JSON & PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is the JSON being pulled in from a feed:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2011-12-20T14:52:50Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "nowplaying": {
    "song": {
     "title": "Silent Night",
     "artist": "Jaci Velasquez",
     "time": "2011-12-20 09:49:51"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I know the feed is coming correctly. I am trying to pull in the "title" with the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php foreach($feed->query->results->nowplaying as $item) { ?>
            <?php echo $item->title; ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

I'm not sure what I am missing. Any tips?! Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? What is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you getting and parsing it? If you are getting it as a string, which you most likely are, you first need to parse it with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You can specify `true` as the second parameter to get an array instead of an object, it's easier to work with.

```
$feed = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can access individual properties like an associative array. Seeing as there are no arrays in that JSON, there is no need for any loop.

```
$song = $feed['query']['results']['nowplaying']['song']['title'];
```

Comment: Perfect. Simple principle of creating an array from string vs creating an object. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
$item->song->title
```

or

```
<?php foreach($feed->query->results->nowplaying->song as $item) { ?>
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: I'm going with Xeon06 answer too. I guessed you were parsing JSON to an object.